# Make a simple IRC bot.

Tags: code-golf, internet

### Task

> Make a simple IRC bot which does simple task like greeting user.

### Detail

(You may see [this RFC document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812).)

Write a complete program that perform these:

1. The program inputs `nickname` and `realname` from the user.

- All `nickname` and `realname` which form is `[A-Za-z0-9]+` should be allowed, but it isn't  important whether other forms are allowed. For example, if the user wants `1234qwerty` as `nickname` and `5319009` as `realname`, the program should use those names, but it isn't important whether the program can use `^^☆Rick Astley☆^^` (which includes non-alphabet&decimals) as (`nickname` or `realname`) or not, even thought this name may be rejected by the server.

2. The program inputs `serverAddress` from the user.

- The form of `serverAddress` is `serverIP:serverPort`, where `serverIP` is the IP address of the server and `serverPort` is the port num of the server.

3. The program connects to port `serverPort` at IRC server `serverIP`, and it should set it's nickname as `nickname` and realname as `realname` by sending `USER realname 0 * :realname` and `NICK nickname`.
4. The program inputs a single `channelName` which doesn't include `#`, and join to the channel `#channelName`.
5. Send a private message `Hello, world!` to the `#channelName` channel like this: `PRIVMSG #channelName :Hello, world!`
6. Then, the program does these:

A. If someone joins, greeting him by saying `Hello, @!` to `#channelName`, where @ is the nickname of him/her.

B. If the program is kicked, try re-joining.

C. If a person is kicked or banned, say `POW HAHA`.

D. If a person leaves (`PART` or `QUIT`), say `Goodbye, @!`, where @ is the nickname of him/her.

E. If someone says some text including `Turing test` or `turing test`, say `I'm a human!`.

F. If someone says some text including `6*9`, quit by sending `QUIT :42` to the server.

G. If someone says some text including `all your base are belong to us`(case-insensitive), quit by sending `QUIT :What you say!` to the server.

H. If someone says some text preceding with a space and above acts aren't performed by the text, say the sum of charcode of all (except the first space) chars in the text.

### If an error is occurred

If an error (such as connection error or invalid `nickname`) is occurred, you can do what you want to do. For example, if the `nickname` is already in use, the program may stop, gets a new `nickname` from the user, or automatically change the `nickname` and retry.

### Restriction

The program

- Should not use any internal functions or libraries which is for IRC client/bot making. i.e. something like IRC client libraries
- Should **prompt what it'll input, before it gets an input**. For example, before inputs `serverAddress`, it should prompt `Write the address of server:`, `serverIP:serverPort >` , `serverAddress >`, or some text that the user can recognize.
- Should work on several IRC servers using UTF-8. (i.e. not for single server)
- 's messages send to server shouldn't be `NOTICE`. (RFC 2812, 3.3.2 Notice : The difference between `NOTICE` and `PRIVMSG` is that automatic replies MUST NEVER be sent in response to a `NOTICE` message.)
- Should send a message where the request came from (`#channelName` or `nickname`).
- Should `PONG` when `PING`ed, of course.

### PS

Well, I just made this, because there was no puzzle about IRC bot.

### Edit

After reading @dmckee's comment, I changed the rule for choosing winner.

1. Default `bonus` = +0
2. If somehow the program can connect to a channel (even if it's not `#channelName`), `bonus` = 1
3. If the program can perform step 1~5, `bonus` *= 2.
4. For each tasks A~H in step 6, if the program implements, `bonus` *= `1.2`.
5. For each six restrictions, if the program follows that, `bonus` *= `1.05`.

and `score = int(codelength/bonus)`.

Program with lowest score is winner. If two answers have same score, then the answer with highest votes wins.

EDIT Edit : I think `1.2` and `1.05` in step 4 and 5 should be adjusted slightly bigger.. What do you think about this?

The winner is decided, however, I think there was too few entries.

Anyone still may submit the code.. :P

Comment: Frankly we have not been very accepting of *"There is no metric, just vote."*. There are things for you to work with here in terms of setting up [an objective metric](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/305/78) for this task. See [Fake error message](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2276/78) for a possible example.

Comment: @dmckee : Sorry, I didn't know that votes was quite subjective.. :(

Comment: @JiminP: Nice save.

Comment: irc bot sounds like a longer golf - I'm in though :)

Comment: clarification: "If the program is kicked, try re-joining." - does this mean from the server or the channel?

Comment: @lunixbochs From the channel.

Comment: no other comers? sadness. playing golf by myself is lonely :)

Comment: I think I can't decide winner now, because there isn't many codes... :(

Comment: @lunixbochs: as a person who uses IRC waaay too much, kicks are channel only.  If you're not on the server anymore, you got killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PHP - 121 points

- 1396 characters
- Follows all steps (including extra) and restrictions

### Score

```
<?php
$bonus = 1;                             //connects to channel
$bonus *= 2;                            //completes steps 1-5
for ($x=0;$x < 8;$x++) $bonus *= 1.2;   //all 8 extra steps
for ($y=0;$y < 6;$y++) $bonus *= 1.05;  //all 6 restrictions
echo (int)(1396 / $bonus);

> 121
```

### Code

```
<?php function w($t){global$s;echo$t."\n";socket_write($s,$t."\r\n");}function m($c,$t){w("PRIVMSG $c :$t");}@$y=fgets;$z=STDIN;echo"nickname>";$n=trim($y($z));echo"realname>";$r=trim($y($z));echo"serverIP:Port>";$a=explode(":",trim($y($z)));$s=socket_create(2,1,6);socket_connect($s,$a[0],$a[1]);w("NICK $n");w("USER $n 0 * :$r");while(1){if((!($l=trim(socket_read($s,512,1))))||(!preg_match("/^(?:\:(\S+)[ ]+)?([^: ][^ ]*)(?:[ ]+([^:].*?))?(?:[ ]+:(.+))?$/",$l,$m)))continue;echo$l."\n";if(preg_match("/(.+)!(.+)@(.+)/",$m[1],$o))$m[1]=$o;if(!empty($m[3]))$p=explode(" ",$m[3]);else$p=array();if(isset($m[4])) $p[]=$m[4];$p=array($m[1],$m[2],$p);$b=$p[2][0];@$e=$p[0][1];@$f=$p[2][1];if($p[1]=="PING")w("PONG :".$b);elseif($p[1]=="376"){echo"#channel>";$c=trim($y($z));$c=(!empty($c))?$c:"#rintaun";w("JOIN $c");}elseif($p[1]=="JOIN")if($e!=$n)m($b,"Hello, $e!");else m($b,"Hello, world!");elseif($p[1]=="KICK")if($f!=$n)m($b,"POW HAHA");else w("JOIN ".$b);elseif(($p[1]=="PART")&&($e!=$n))m($b,"Goodbye, $e!");elseif(($p[1]=="QUIT")&&($e!=$n))m($c,"Goodbye, $e!");elseif($p[1]=="PRIVMSG")if(preg_match("/[Tt]uring test/",$f))m(($b==$n)?$e:$b,"I'm a human!");elseif(strstr($f,"6*9")){w("QUIT :42");break;}elseif(stristr($f,"all your base are belong to us")){w("QUIT :What you say!");break;}elseif($f[0]==" "){$q=str_split(substr($f,1));$u=0;foreach($q AS $d)$u+=ord($d);m(($b==$n)?$e:$b,$u);}}
```

#### Side Note

My answer actually differs from the instructions very slightly; the instructions say to use the `realname` as the first parameter to the `USER` command when registering, but I used the nickname instead. This is because the `realname` is allowed to have spaces, while this parameter is not. It's something of a moot point, though, since switching in the variable for `realname` would be the exact same character count.

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 125 points

- 304 chars
- follows steps 1-5 (works for me on irc.freenode.net:6667. if you try there, remember IDENT might take a while, so give it 20+ seconds to connect and speak)
- follows 4 restrictions (assuming the NOTICE restriction which is a bit unclear. the UTF restriction counts because python won't choke if it doesn't need to parse any UTF).

### score math (python):

```
bonus = 1 # connects to channel
bonus *= 2 # steps 1-5
for i in xrange(4):
    bonus *= 1.05 # 4 restrictions

int(304.0/bonus)
> 125
```

### code:

```
import socket
i=raw_input
u=i('user# ')
n=i('nick# ')
h,p=i('host:port# ').split(':',1)
p=int(p)
c='#'+i('chan# ')
z=0
while 1:
 try:
  def s(m): z.send(m+'\r\n')
  z.recv(9)
 except:
  z=socket.socket();z.connect((h,p));s('USER '+n+' 0 * :'+n);s('NICK '+n);s('JOIN '+c);s('PRIVMSG '+c+' :Hello, world!')
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 66 points

- 666 characters
- all substeps
- half of the restrictions

### Score

```
use 5.010;
$bonus = 1;              # connects to channel
$bonus *= 2;             # steps 1 to 5
$bonus *= 1.2 for 1..8;  # substeps A to H
$bonus *= 1.05 for 1..3; # restrictions 3, 4, 6
say int(666 / $bonus);
> 66
```

### Code

(newlines for presentation only, not counted let alone acceptable)

```
use POE"Component::IRC";$_='sub _start{Zregister,all);Z"connect")}subX001{
Zjoin=>$c);ZY"Hello, world!")}*Xquit=*Xpart=*Xjoin=sub{$g=$_[STATE]=~/t/?G
oodbye:Hello;$_=$_[ARG0];/\w+/;ZY"$g, $&!")};subXkick{$_=$_[ARG2];/\w+/;Z$
&eq$n?"join":Y"POW HAHA")}subXpublic{$_=$_[ARG2];if(/turing test/i){ZY"I\'
m a human!")}elsif(/6\*9/){Zquit,42)}elsif(/all your base are belong to us
/i){Zquit,"What you say!")}elsif(/^ /){$t=-32;$t+=ord for/./g;ZY$t)}}chop(
($n,$r,$s,$c)=<>);$c="#$c";$i=POE::Component::IRC->spawn(nick,$n,ircname,$
r,server,$s)';s/Z/\$i->yield(/g;s/Y/privmsg,\$c,/g;S/X/ irc_/g;eval;POE::S
ession->create(package_states,[main,[grep*$_{CODE},%::]]);POE::Kernel->run
```

**Side Note**

The "ALL YOUR BASE ARE BELONG TO US" substep is most probably not worth its character count, but if I dropped it I wouldn't have the nice character count.  Bugger.

Comment: +1 for 66 points and 666 characters. Is that intentional or did you get that by accident?

Comment: @nyuszika7h I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 65 points

- 574 Chars
- Steps 1-5, 6(A-G) and restrictions on libs, UTF-8, no NOTICE & PONG
- Takes commandline args in the form of server:6667 botnick botuser channel

## Score

```
bonus = 0       # We've done nothing yet
bonus += 1      # Connects to channel
bonus *= 2      # Step 1 - 5

for n in 1..7
    bonus *= 1.2    # A - G
end

for n in 1..4
    bonus *= 1.05   # 4 constraints
end

puts (574/bonus).to_i
> 65
```

## Code

```
require'socket'
a=ARGV
c="##{a[3]}"
h,p=a[0].split':'
s=TCPSocket.open(h,p)
m="PRIVMSG #{c} :"
s.puts"USER #{a[2]} 0 * :#{a[2]}\nNICK #{a[1]}\nJOIN #{c}\n#{m}Hello, world!"
while l=s.gets
case l
when/\:(.+?)!(.+)JOIN/
s.puts"#{m}Hello, #{$1}!"
when/KICK (.+?) (.+?) \:(.+)/
if $2==a[1]
s.puts"JOIN #{c}"
else
s.puts"#{m}POW HAHA"
end
when/\:(.+?)\!(.+)(PART|QUIT)/
s.puts"#{m}Goodbye, #{$1}!"
when/turing test/i
s.puts"#{m}I'm a human!"
when/6\*9/
s.puts"QUIT :42"
when/all your base are belong to us/i
s.puts"QUIT :What you say!"
when/PING \:(.+)/
puts"PONG #{$1}"
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 28 points

- 249 Chars
- Same bot as my other solution, but slightly cheating maybe by applying compression.
- http://coolfire.insomnia247.nl/golfbot-inflate.rb (As pasting this code probably won't work too well.)

## Score

```
bonus = 0       # We've done nothing yet
bonus += 1      # Connects to channel
bonus *= 2      # Step 1 - 5

for n in 1..7
    bonus *= 1.2    # A - G
end

for n in 1..4
    bonus *= 1.05   # 4 constraints
end

puts (249/bonus).to_i
>  28
```

## Code

```
require 'zlib'
b=<<'E'
x�]�_o�0���)��q�-KFBcdf��߃�P�S�B�����(N�Л��s~�� ��(�_$U6��5G�)�r�BB������J�{��� nNhlO�f)QQdJ�g��'�yP�!!����K�ɫ��[Ё�Ə{0�F]ѽ�m�2���GŐP��p`   ��I����E�+�* z�                                                                                                                                                           )jrmKR�ˮ�%�
#��nQaJ�H��<�ZT���虦T3.�$D('�hw��a�/'��&�_ei�}o��1���M$����H��J�$��������V"���"��'��|A�`<��3L)Y��Z|� e�� ���m�é��ǚ�ڎu��J�����Vq~(ح�
E
eval Zlib::Inflate.new.inflate b
```